# Can any one explain time complexity of below code (big O notation)

Tags: python, big-o

Can anyone explain time complexity of the code below? in Big O notation. Thanks in Advance.

I was trying to get time complexity for one of my codes. I think its O(logn). But in code we have few delete operations.

```
class Solution:
def merge( arr):
    i=0
    arr.sort(key=lambda x:x[0],reverse=False)
    while i<(len(arr)-1):

        if arr[i][1] >= arr[i+1][0]:
            if arr[i][1]>=arr[i+1][1]:
                del(arr[i+1])
                if i>0:
                    i-=1
            else:
                arr[i][1]=arr[i+1][1]
                del(arr[i+1])
                if i>0:
                    i-=1
            continue
        i+=1
    return arr

#driver code:
arr=[[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[9,11],[12,14]]
ans=Solution.merge(arr)
print(ans)
```

Comment: What do you think it is? What part are you stuck on in regards to figuring out the solution? What thoughts have you had so far?

Comment: Do you understand big O yourself? What do you need explained exactly? You can [edit] to add details. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Sorry this was my 1st time posting in StackOverflow. Had issue submitting the whole code and my question. finally I have asked my question.

Comment: `del` is O(n) (since it has to move everything after the element that you delete). See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity for the complexity of some common operations internally in Python. Any call to `sort` won't be O(log n) either.

Comment: A minor hint: your guess of logn is incorrect. As a starting point, what's the time complexity of different sections of code? i.e. what is everything before the while loop and everything after?

Comment: Sort have O(n log n)
del have O(n)
loop have O(logn)

So time complexity = O(n log n)+O(n)+O(log n) ?